# Nested balls in normed space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I'll ask probably a really easy question.

Suppose that $(X,\lVert \cdot\rVert)$ be a normed space. If $B(a;r)\subset B(a;R)$, then $r\leq R$.

Obviously this example does not hold when $X$ is a metric space since one can take $X$ with discrete metric and we see that $B(a;2)\subset B(a;3/2)$ but $2>3/2$.

I believe that we need to use some structure in normed space which does not exist in metrix space!
Thank you!

Comment: @EricWofsey Are you saying that the answer below by jjagmath is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: suppose $r>R$ and consider $v = a + \frac{r+R}{2} u$ where $u$ is any unit vector (and what do you need to ask about $X$ to be able to construct a unit vector).

Comment: $X$ should have at least one nonzero element? Suppose $b$ is such an element, then consider $b/\lVert b\rVert$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. If $X=\{0\}$ the statement is false.